# Need to create dynamic folder in powershell and use it as a variable in copy-item

Tags: powershell

I need to create a dynamic folder in power shell and copy some files to one more location.I am using the below script.

```
$fso = new-object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject

$fso.CreateFolder("d:\logs $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)")
```

I am trying to pass the above created folder path into a variable  and use it in copy item like below

```
$A=$fso.CreateFolder("d:\logs $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)")
```

and then

```
copy-item c:\logs $A
```

I am not sure what I am missing here,Can you please help me out,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid COM-Objects when you can. Try something like this:

```
#Create folder
$f = New-Item "d:\logs\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)" -ItemType Directory -Force

#Copy all files inside c:\logs to new folder (if you need to include files from subfolders, add -Recurse parameter)
Copy-Item C:\logs\* $f.FullName
```

Comment: copy-item is throwing errors,when copying from c:\program files,space is becoming some issue

Comment: Wrap your paths in quotes. `"c:\my path" `.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use COM object. Directory creation is done with `New-Item` cmdlet, and an easy shortcut is to use `md` like so,

```
# Directory name is created with a format string
$dirName = "c:\temp\logs_{0}" -f (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss")
$dirName # Check the output
c:\temp\logs_2013-11-08-10-18-42

# Create dir if needed
if(-not (test-path $dirName)) {
    md $dirName | out-null
} else {
    write-host "$dirName already exists!"
}
```